# Independence two stochastic processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, independence

being $X, Y$ two continuous processes, $\theta \in R$

- $U_t=\sin{(\theta)}X_t+\cos{(\theta)}Y_t$
- $V_t=\cos{(\theta)}X_t-\sin{(\theta)}Y_t$

I have to show that $(U_t)$ and $(V_t)$ are independent Brownian motions if and only if $(X_t)$ and $(Y_t)$ are independent Brownian motions.

My approach has been the following...if $X_t$, $Y_t$ are Brownian motions then also $U_t$ and $V_t$ are also normal, then I can compute the var/covariance matrix and nullify all the terms but the ones on the main diagonal...is that a good approach? In this case $\theta$ would be $\pi/2$ and $X$, $Y$ must be independent.

The problem, then, asks me also for a geometric property of the 2-dim Brownian motion that should appear evident from the problem itself...(? can you post a link in which I can go deeper?)

Comment: "geomtric property of the 2-dim brownian motion" Invariance by the rotations.

Comment: thx! evidently the exercise wanted me to notice the coefficients of the processes are the elements of a 2x2 rotation matrix, and link this to the rotational invariance (which I wasn't aware of) of the 2-dim brownian motion

Comment: Funny: the accepted answer only proves a part of one implication (and the OP quite clearly says so), namely, that if X and Y are independent then so are U and V. Much more work is needed to solve the question, since it asks to show that if X and Y are independent Brownian motions then so are U and V, and the reverse implication.

Comment: if $U_t, V_t$ are brownian motions, wouldn't be sufficient (and necessary) to compute the covariance between them and set equal to zero?
of course, once shown $U_t$ and $V_t$ are brownian motions...

Comment: $$E[U_t U_s]=s+\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(E[X_tY_s]+E[X_sY_t])$$
$$E[V_tV_s]=s-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(E[X_tY_s]+E[X_sY_t])$$

I would conclude $V_t$, $U_t$ are brownian motion if and only if $X_t$, $Y_t$ are two independent brownian motions...

Comment: and then $$cov(U_t,V_t)=cov(X_t,Y_t)[\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta]$$

Comment: Here is an exercise to let you get an idea of what is missing from a complete proof: find W gaussian and Z gaussian such that cov(W,Z)=0 but W and Z are not independent.

Comment: I see...$cov(X,Y)=0$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition for independence, I have to show that the vector $(U_t,V_t)$ is gaussian, $$Z_t=U_t+V_t$$$$Z_t=X_t(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)+Y_t(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)$$
and this (Z_t being gaussian) should hold iff $X_t$, $Y_t$ are independent

Comment: The assertion that (U,V) is gaussian if and only if (X,Y) is (gaussian and) independent, is quite untrue. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did yes, sorry, it should have been "if $U_t$, $V_t$ are uncorrelated and jointly normal, then they are independent" (of course the opposite is not true...it would not make sense eheh)
For the correlation, I computed above, for the joint normality I have to verify that every linear combination of $U_t$ and $V_t$ is a normal distribution (I think I can move the same argument to the brownian motion). Is that correct?

Comment: Until you write down a full solution, I cannot answer (of course, this whole conversation is a bit surreal, on a page where an answer got already accepted).

Comment: @Did I wrote everything I have been thinking...but I still think I'm missing something (actually I think I showed only the "if" part...but I don't have any idea on how to show independence of $X_t$,$Y_t$ is the "only" one condition)

Answer (score 0):

$$
E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]
$$
is my claim for independence.

So taking U and V lets compute $E[UV]$
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
U_tV_t&=& (\sin (\theta) X_t +\cos (\theta) Y_t)(\cos (\theta) X_t -\sin (\theta) Y_t),\\
&=&\sin \theta \cos \theta X_t^2 + \cos^2(\theta)Y_tX_t - \sin^2(\theta)X_tY_t - \sin \theta \cos \theta Y_t^2,\\
\implies E[U_tV_t] &=& \sin \theta \cos \theta \left(E[X_t^2]-E[Y_t^2]\right) + \left(\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)\right)E[X_tY_t].\tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
lets compute $E[U_t]E[V_t]$
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
E[U_t] &=& \sin (\theta) E[X_t] + \cos (\theta) E[Y_t],\\ 
E[V] &=& \cos (\theta) E[X_t] - \sin (\theta) E[Y_t].\\
\implies E[U]E[V] &=& \sin \theta \cos \theta \left(E[X_t]^2 -E[Y_t]^2\right)+ \left(\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta\right)E[X_t]E[Y_t].\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Now for $U_t$ and $V_t$ to be independent

$$
E[U_tV_t] = E[U_t]E[V_t]
$$
equating Eq.1 and 2
we find
$$
\sin \theta \cos \theta \left(E[X_t^2]-E[Y_t^2]\right) + \left(\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)\right)E[X_tY_t] = \\
\sin \theta \cos \theta \left(E[X_t]^2 -E[Y_t]^2\right)+ \left(\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta\right)E[X_t]E[Y_t]
$$
we already see that the first terms respectively cancel to yield
$$
\left(\cos^2(\theta) - \sin^2(\theta)\right)E[X_tY_t] = \left(\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta\right)E[X_t]E[Y_t]
$$
or 
$$
E[X_tY_t] = E[X_t]E[Y_t]
$$

thus to ensure that $U_t$ and $V_t$ are independent we require $X_t$ and $Y_t$ to be also.

Comment: you're right, I was assuming the X, Y were brownian motion, while the statement doesn't tell so.
The only thing I didn't understand is why $E^2[X_t]-E^2[Y_t]=E[X^2_t]-E[Y^2_t]$, for brownian motion they should be different ($0$ the squared mean, and $t$ the second moment...)

Comment: and what about the geometric property of the 2-dim brownian motion that this exercise should make evident?

ps about the question in the previous comment...ok, they're both zero eheh

Comment: I am still trying to figure out the second part. I am not to sure how, or what they are trying to gain from the question..

Answer (score 0):

First let's compute the conditions for which $U_t$, $V_t$ are two brownian motions.
$U_t$ and $V_t$ are two brownian motions if:
$$E[U_t U_s]=s$$
$$E[V_t V_s]=s$$
Computing these two quantities:
$$E[U_t U_s]=s+\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(E[X_tY_s]+E[X_s Y_t])$$
$$E[V_t V_s]=s-\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)(E[X_tY_s]+E[X_s Y_t])$$
If $X_t$ and $Y_t$ are independent brownian motions, $U_t$ and $V_t$ are brownian motions.
To check independence between $U_t$ and $V_t$, we need to verify that $cov(U_t,V_t)=0$ and that every linear combination of $U_t,V_t$ is a brownian motion.
$$cov(U_t,V_t)=cov(X_t,Y_t)[\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta]$$
(If $X_t$,$Y_t$ are independent then $cov(U_t,V_t)=0$)
and $$Z_t=X_t\lambda_1(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)+Y_t\lambda_2(cos\theta-\sin\theta)$$
$Z_t$ is a brownian motion process if and only if $X_t$,$Y_t$ are two independent brownian motion processes.

Comment: You are making so many twists and turns that it is difficult to see what the whole constitutes a proof of, in the end... For example, you start assuming... what? That X and Y are two independent Brownian motions, presumably, and you want to show that U and V are two independent Brownian motions, right? This conclusion cannot be reduced to E(U_tU_s)=s and E(V_tV_s)=s alone. As a first step, you might want to state clearly which properties would establish that U (alone) is a Brownian motion (then we'll talk about V...).